# [playframework 1.2.3][scala 0.91]passing "/" as part of a parameter in play framework

Tags: routes, playframework

In my routes file I map a path as `/s/{ctype}/{name}` to a controller that accepts two parameters.

The problem I have right now is that if name part has a `"/"` in it, for example `cbr/mfg` which is passed as after encoding as `"cbr%2Fmfg"` still play framework return a 404 response, but it works fine any other name that doesn't have `"/"` in it. Is there a way to solve this problem?

Comment: after searching somemore was able to solve the problem with a regex parameter, this is what ended up with /s/ctype/{<.*>name} it seemed to work.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this

```
/s/{ctype}/{<.*>name}
```